# Python Upgrading leads to terminal... not opening

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal, zsh

I just upgraded python in ubuntu to python 3.10 to use the match/case statements, but now, my terminal won't open. Anywhere. I tired opening it on Visual Studio Code, but it says the path does not exist. Gnome terminal and terminator won't even give any feedback. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with i3wm, my shell is zsh, and here are the commands i used (i modified them from [this site](http://web.mit.edu/6.00/www/handouts/pybuntu.html) and [this site](https://fostips.com/install-python-3-10-ubuntu-20-04/)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.6 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python2.6 10
sudo update-alternatives --config python
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

For what I remember my previous python version was somewhere around 3.7.

If you prefer, here are the specs from above:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Shell: zsh (oh-my-zsh)
- WM: i3
- Terminal: gnome-terminal

**Important:** Please remember I do not have access to a terminal. I have still not tried recovery mode, but if you have a non-termianl based solution, it is preferred.

Comment: I don't know how it works for Linux but at least on Windows you have to add Python to the PATH, also did you install `Python2.6` too: `--install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.6 10`?

Comment: Well, I have python in the "path", but I didn't have 2.6... That might be a problem, but why the terminal won't open?

Comment: you certainly don't need `Python2.6` so that can be uninstalled, why did you follow the instructions word for word? you had to adjust and not install 2.6. why the terminal doesn't open? no idea

Comment: There are OS tools which use Python 3.8 -- the version which comes with Ubuntu 20.04 -- and those tools may not work right or at all with 3.10 so it's not recommended -- to my knowledge -- to change too much. Another solution, possibly easier to manage, to the various versions of Python and dependencies is to use something like `pipenv`.

Comment: I have already done it, though. I don't know how to undo it and I don't have access to shells...

Answer (score 10):

Just found a way to undo it. If you encounter the same problem, here is what I did:

Ctrl+Alt+Fn and a few F buttons (F1, F2, F3...) until I got to a tty menu.
I logged in as myself (not root), and ran `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1` to make the default python 2.8 with `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` again. Then it worked properly.

Answer (score 5):

## Edited

### New Answer

I found a better way to install your preferred `python` version. It's more stable and more secure than using `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` repository.

Sure now this is not a direct answer to the problem you had anymore. But I am editing this answer here in hope to help you and anyone that may want to install `python3.10` in a machine that does not come with it installed by default.

You can use [**asdf**](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html), which is a tool version manager. With it you may install any python version you want, independent of your OS. It is gonna be more verbose, but works perfectly well, without any conflict with some pre-installed `python` version.

To avoid problems when installing `asdf` and `python`, install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

to make sure everything is up to date.

#### Installing asdf

To install `asdf`, first we clone from the repository and the branch of `asdf` version we want (Please note that the version specified in the end of the command may change. I just followed the [documentation](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_2-download-asdf)):

```
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.10.0
```

Now you only got to add a few lines to the end of your script configuration file. It may change according to your shell, but again, check the [documentation](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf) for specific instructions (including `zsh`).

To find out what kind of terminal you're using, you can run:

```bash
echo $SHELL
```

If your're using `bash` then you can add the following to the end of your `~/.bashrc` (yes, the dots are included):

```
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
```

After that, you just have to restart your terminal.

#### Installing python3.10 (or any version you want)

Now with `asdf` installed, you should install a plugin to manage multiple `python` versions. To do that, just run the command:

```
asdf plugin-add python
```

To globally install `python3.10.4` in your system, run:

```
asdf install python 3.10.4
```

And then:

```
asdf global python 3.10.4
```

Lastly, run:

```
asdf reshim
```

This last command is a somewhat refresh for `asdf` to work properly after globally installing libraries. Run it whenever you install something with `asdf`, just to be sure.

No need to worry about running this command after installing some package or module with pip though (well, at least I never had).

Credits to [Kenzie Academy](https://kenzie.com.br/). Learned it there.

---

### Old Answer

I ran exactly into the same problem. I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132349/terminal-not-opening-up-after-upgrading-python-to-3-7).

At first, I tried to simply open the `gnome-terminal` file without a terminal and change it, but it didn't work, because using a GUI I had no sudo permissions. So the workaround that worked for me and I expect that may work for you, was to open the file with VSCode and then used the VSCode integrated terminal to run the following command:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Of course you don't have to use `nano`, you could use `vim` or something else. Anyway, once there, you can change the first line of the file, which is a comment, from

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

Ubuntu 20.04 is well compatible with `python3.8`, so that's why I suggested you putting `python3.8` there but you could surely test if some other version works.

This is not a way to go back to `python3.8`. You will still have the add-ons of `python3.10`.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above Solutions worked for me.
However after searching a lot for an hour,

(Replace the Python version which was earlier present on your system, instead of 3.8)

`sudo apt reinstall python3 python3-minimal python3.8 python3.8-minimal`

this command did the magic!

(PS - Make sure you haven't changed anything in the usr/bin/gnome-terminal file)
First line should be
`#!/usr/bin/python3`

Lesson Learnt -
Dont upgrade your OS Python Version manually EVER!

Comment: This is the most useful answer that i had. Work fine on Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue and I had performed similar steps to reach the same. I tried @Rafael's response but did not notice any change. I could not open terminal but VSCode terminal was working. I noticed vscode was using an updated python. I fixed it by removing existing symbolic link and creating a new one. Terminal opened instantly.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Shell : zsh (Oh-my-zsh)

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```